# Pandas empty data due to no columns to parse

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Im not sure the cause of pandas not being able to read the colums from the csv, Im assuming it has something to do with the format of my CSV but it seems like this is a okay format to input data to pandas.
sdata.csv

```
index,timestamp,low,open,close,high,volume
0,17-Jul-2019,300,300,300,300,2
1,03-Aug-2019,80,300,80,80,1
2,06-Aug-2019,75,80,75,80,4
3,07-Aug-2019,75,75,75,75,4
4,08-Aug-2019,75,75,75,80,3
```

```py
df = pd.read_csv('sdata.csv')
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=df['timestamp'], y=df['low'],  # Data
    mode='lines', name='low'  # Additional options
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(x=df['timestamp'], y=df['open'], mode='lines', name='open')
trace3 = go.Scatter(x=df['timestamp'], y=df['close'], mode='lines', name='close')
trace4 = go.Scatter(x=df['timestamp'], y=df['high'], mode='lines', name='high')
trace5 = go.Scatter(x=df['timestamp'], y=df['volume'], mode='lines', name='volume')
layout = go.Layout(title='Simple Plot from csv data',
                   plot_bgcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)')

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5], layout=layout)

# Plot data in the notebook
py.iplot(fig, filename='simple-plot-from-csv')
```

```
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 532, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to close the file before opening it again with pandas.